# Ubuntu desktop isn`t focussing after minimising a window on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, 16.04, window

When I open a window (for example Nautilus), I can see in the panel the name of the currently focused program (Nautilus), but when I minimize this window, I can still see in the unity panel the word Nautilus, and a menu for that and also the shadow below the panel disappears.

The situation is even worse if I choose to show menu in the title of the window, not in the panel of the system. In this case the behaviour will be the same, but there is no information of currently focused windows at all.

What I need to do to focus Desktop is to click in any place of the desktop. 
This is a very annoying bug. Please, help me with it! (This repeats with any window, Nautilus is here for example)

***When Nautilus is open (everything is ok).***

[image: nautilus]

**Immediately after minimizing Nautilus window (a bug: desktop isn't focused, shadow disappears).**

[image: minimized nautilus]

Comment: OK, suddenly i found out what was the problem. I have a Telegram from atareo ppa, and when i try to launch Telegram in a tray via
`/opt/telegram/Telegram -startintray`
this strange behavior appears. If I quit Telegram (or start it as usual) everithing is back to normal

Comment: Its just a simple stupid workaround that wont solve your problem, but in case you dont manage to solve it, you can set mouse focus to `sloppy` so you wont need to click in the desktop to get rid of that panel. You can do it with this command `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences focus-mode 'sloppy'`

Comment: You mean you solved it?

Comment: hmmm, yes, this still happens if i run telegram as described above, but it`s not the unity problem i think. I decided to myself not to start telegram in a tray ever, and everithing will be good. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with Telegram from atareo ppa. When i try to launch Telegram in a tray via `/opt/telegram/Telegram -startintray` then this strange behavior appears. If I quit Telegram (or start it as usual) everithing is back to normal. Don`t now exactly why Telegram produces this bug though. But it's aceptable workaround for me, thanks all!